# Storing user related data and accessing it by User ID

Tags: python, django, django-models

The Django website have user authentication, where only couple users are meant to log in, so it's pretty private. If user log in, then he gets data from multiple API systems, what is presented in the website. I have a database, where I have different API tokens for each userID and other database for user accounts for Django authentication, which is the Django system made by default. How should I get ID:s of both databases, so I could then make a API request with the correct API token?

Comment: what are these API tokens? why do you think you need two different databases?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your databases configuration. But you can [manually select database for QuerySet with ".using()" method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset).

For that setup:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'main_db', # Here we store Users
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    },
    'auth': {
        'NAME': 'auth_db',  # Here we store API tokens
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    },
```

Then, to get API token for User with specified email you can use:

```
user = User.objects.using('default').get(email='john@example.com')
token = ApiKey.objects.using('apikeys').get(user_id=user.id)
```

Comment: What if I don't make second database at all, and put API-tokens to same database where the user information is in, which has been made in Django's default administrator page? I don't know how that could be possible though.